# ExecuteReader() Object cant be converted

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have set up a mySql database on a server, and now i want to reach it in order for me to make a webservice. Firstly i just want to test if i can grab an entity from my query in my method (OneEntity), and put it into my list.

```
    public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
    {
        return new List<Person> {
        new Person{ ID = 0, First = OneEntity(), Last ="Example"}
        };

    } 
    public string OneEntity()
    {
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection mySqlConnection;
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
        String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySql"].ToString();
        mySqlConnection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
        cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'name' FROM 'CustomerDb' WHERE 'id' = 0";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = mySqlConnection;

        mySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        mySqlConnection.Close();
        return reader;
     }
```

I am **not** very experienced in c# and are therefore not sure if im doing it correct. However in my cmd.ExecuteReader() (Object i guess it is?!??!) i get that it

> cannot implicitly convert type 'MySql.Data.MySqlDataReader' to
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader'

What am i doing wrong here?? obviously my return is not correct either, as i specified my method to be 'string'.. but even though i type in a string, the error doesn't dissapear?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you shoud use `MySqlDataReader` not  `SqlDataReader`

```
MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

code should return `string` not the `reader` in your case.

To return the first item use this `return reader.GetString(0);`

Comment: Thank you! How do i make it return a string then?

Comment: string strValue = Reader [0].ToString();

Comment: If you are sure that you will get only one record then use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteReader

Comment: Thank you again! it does however tell me that there is "no current query in data reader"

Comment: I think your table is empty or there is no record in table with id =0

Comment: oh yea, i modified my id but it now says that it cant connect to any of the specified mysql hosts.. much worse

Comment: check DB connectivity or connection string

Comment: how can i check the connectivity in the most simple way? - again thank you for taking your time with me.

Comment: Just write mySqlConnection.Open(); and remove all the extra code. If everything is fine it will run else some issue

Comment: @JeppeChristensen improved the code. thank you